# What Schema.org type should we use for our offerings?

Tags: schema.org

At Withlocals.com we offer activities such as tours, and home-dinners organised by hosts, to our guests. Some have actual dates at which they are available, but many are always available on request.

Hosts how offer their services occasionally can be easily seen as Performers hosting Events, however hosts that offer their services on request (I feel) are more like products.

The part after booking is easy, emails and pages can describe bookings, reservations, etc. But I am still not quite certain which Schema type to use Products or Events?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Offer`](http://schema.org/Offer) in both cases, and only associate an [`Event`](http://schema.org/Event) (or one of its sub-types, e.g., [`FoodEvent`](http://schema.org/FoodEvent)) if you know a specific date.

The [`offers` property](http://schema.org/offers) allows to reference an `Offer` from an `Event`.

Comment: So the structure would be : Product -> Offers* -> [optional] Event? Sounds good!